# BigQuery Case - for col1 if col 2 equals 'a' & 'b' then True else = False

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, conditional-statements, case

I'm really struggling with the syntax here...

I'm trying to get the following data:

```
Col1  Col2
001   a
001   b
002   a
003   b
004   a
```

To show as follows

```
Col1  Col2  Col3
001   a     True
001   b     True
002   a     False
003   b     False
004   a     False
```

I'm in big query and know my statement isn't correct but was looking at something like this:

```
case
when Col1 is not null then
case 
    when Col2 = 'a' and Col2 = 'b' then "True"
else "False"
end
Duplicates
```

I'm sure the issue is with the first condition, but can't figure out how to handle it.
Could someone please give me some direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *,
  2 = COUNT(DISTINCT IF(Col2 IN ('a', 'b'), Col2, NULL)) OVER(PARTITION BY Col1) AS Col3
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

if to apply to sample data from your example  - output is

```
Row Col1    Col2    Col3     
1   001     a       true     
2   001     b       true     
3   002     a       false    
4   003     b       false    
5   004     a       false
```

Comment: glad it helped. consider also voting up the answer if it helped :o)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have only 'a' and 'b', you can use `case` and window functions:

```
select t.*
       ( (col2 = 'a' and countif(col2 = 'b') over (partition by col1) > 0 or
         (col2 = 'b' and countif(col2 = 'a') over (partition by col1) > 0
       ) as col3     
from t;
```

Comment: Hey Gordon, there a several more columns of data, so I'm not sure how I can apply this?

Comment: @NickG . . . This answers the question that you asked here.